# How can I filter the latest occurring filename from a certain directory that matches a filetype?

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote this to check if there's a file created at a certain directory and give me the newest file.  How do I modify my regex to only pick up the latest file of a certain file type (say only `.txt`)?

```
my $DIR="C:\\Dropbox\\AnalysesLogs";
opendir(my $DH, $DIR) or die "Error opening $DIR: $!";
my @files = map { [ stat "$DIR/$_", $_ ] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);

sub rev_by_date { $b->[9] <=> $a->[9] }
my @sorted_files = sort rev_by_date @files;
my @newest = @{$sorted_files[0]};
my $newestfile = pop(@newest);
```

Currently, `$newestfile` would be the latest file, but it is an undesired type. I only wish to see the very latest `.txt` type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` again:

```
my @files = map { [ stat "$DIR/$_", $_ ] } grep { /\.txt$/ } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
```

This assumes you have no subdirectories with a `.txt` suffix.

This can be further simplified since it'll filter out the 2 dot directories:

```
my @files = map { [ stat "$DIR/$_", $_ ] } grep { /\.txt$/ } readdir($DH);
```

Comment: To avoid subdirectories ending with `.txt` you can modify the grep `... grep { -f && /\.txt$/ } ...` will only find files and then search for the `.txt` type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do, instead of readdir:

```
my @files = map { [ stat $_, $_ ] } <$DIR/*.txt>;
```

See [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) operator.